# How to check which JTree is selected in mouse clicked event?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtree, mouselistener

I'm making app. in Netbeans in Java.  In my class I have 3 `JTree` instances. I want to check which tree's node is clicked or selected on mouse clicked event of tree.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

- [`addTreeSelectionListener(TreeSelectionListener)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#addTreeSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener%29)
- [`EventObject.getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) (`TreeSelectionEvent` extends it).